# Having problems with gzip

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, gzip, pagespeed

I have some problems with gzip encoding and I just can't figure them out!
I added in my htaccess "AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE ... ..." and I used the tool from http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php to check if my pages are encoded properly. The tool says everything is ok.

The problem is that when I check the pages with the web developer tools from chrome or firebug, they don't recognize the pages as gzipped. In the headers section the "content-encoding: gzip" does not appear and PageSpeed also says they are not encoded and recommends me to encode them.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Adi Ulici

Answer (score 1):

`AddOutputFilterByType` is deprecated try `AddOutputFilter` instead, eg

AddOutputFilter DEFLATE php js css html

Comment: I tried it now, unfortunately the same result. The gzip tool says it's okay, but pagespeed says it's not and the header is not ok. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: @AdiUlici is mod_deflate enabled

Comment: Yes, it is. I checked in ubuntu also, and it's ok. I think windows 7 has a problem in sending the headers correctly..